# Android - cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.ByteArrayEntity required: org.apache.http.HttpEntity

Tags: android, json, httpclient, asynchttpclient, loopj

I am using `loopj AsyncHttpClient` to call web services. I am trying register a user. So I need to send `JSON` data to Web Service.

```
ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

client.post(getApplicationContext(), "http://10.0.3.2:8080/WebService/rest/user/insert", entity, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
```

When I put cursor on the `entity` in `client.post` line it gives this error.

> cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.ByteArrayEntity required: org.apache.http.HttpEntity

Example That I am trying is also from stack-overflow - [Send JSON as a POST request to server by AsyncHttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594572/send-json-as-a-post-request-to-server-by-asynchttpclient)

Libraries that I am using

```
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'
```

Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the `cz.msebera.android:htttpclient:4.3.6` libray and follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340629/cant-import-org-apache-http-httpresponse-in-android-studio to implemenmt apache httpclient. The use HtttpEntity insted of ByteArrayEntity

Comment: @TominB I will do it and let you know. Thanks for the answer.